# function declaration inside object/class

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object, declaration

I have the following question : in Node/Javascript why this function declaration is wrong inside an object or a class??

```
var obj = {
  function x() {
    /* code */
  },
  bar: function() {
    /* code */
  }
};
```

the first function declaration `x()` cause

```
  function x() {
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

i don't understand why i can't use the `function` keyword inside an object or a class , what difference does it make when using `function x()` or just `x()`, just `x()` works fine , but adding `function` keyword in front of it - cause the above problem. why ?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.json.org/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in Node/Javascript why this function declaration is wrong inside an object or a class??

Of course it's wrong, in JavaScript an `object` is pairs of key/values, separated with comma. With your code, you are breaking this syntax, because you are not declaring a property in your case, you need to specify the key before writing `function x()`.

If you refer to [MDN **Object initializer** reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) you can see that:

> An object initializer is a comma-delimited list of zero or more pairs
>   of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in
>   curly braces ({}).

And if you check the [**New notations in ECMAScript 2015** section of Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) you will see the difference between writing `function x()`, `x()` or just `x()`.

And according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions) these are possible **[Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions)** syntaxes:

```
var o = {
  property: function (parameters) {},
  get property() {},
  set property(value) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a key in Javascript to their objects, the second one works because you have a key assigned to it that is bar, in the first one not. Try adding the key before the function declaration,like this:

```
var obj = {
  foo:function x() {
    /* code */
  },
  bar: function() {
    /* code */
  }
};
```